# “cause” or “causes”?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Here’s a sentence that I translated from Chinese.
My American friend just proofread it for me, but we had an disagreement over the word “cause”. He said that I should’ve use “cause” instead of “causes”, but he didn’t know why.
He said that it felt odd to use “causes”.
Could anyone explain it to me regarding why I should use “cause”?

Here’s the sentence:

> It’s not inappropriate to focus on eliminating highly susceptible places or circumstances for fire, but the problem is: Are illegal rooftop subletted rooms the only factor that **causes** such tragedies?

Please let me know if there’s anything else in my sentence that’s weirdly constructed, thank you!

Comment: **that causes such tragedies** modifies  (singular) "factor". You are correct. See this question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/148918/follow-the-antecedent-adjective-clauses

Comment: I think my friend was perplexed by my weirdly composed sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question at the end of that sentence sounds odd because you are mixing a plural noun (i.e., *rooms*) with a singular noun (*factor*) before the verb.

Consider:

> Do illegal rooftop subletted rooms cause such tragedies?

In that wording, the plural *rooms* matches with the verb *cause*.

Or:

> Is this the only factor that causes such tragedies?

In that form, the singular *factor* matches with the verb *causes*.

Your sentence mixes the plural *rooms* with the singular *factor*, making it hard for you to figure out which form the verb cause(s) should take. (This isn’t necessarily ungrammatical, but sometimes this can make a sentence sound odd.)

I think one easy way to remedy this is to use the noun form of *cause*:

> Are illegal rooftop subletted rooms the only cause of such tragedies?

but you would have to decide if that shifts the meaning of the sentence too far away from your original intent. If so, you could try removing the *that*, and  using an -ing form:

> Are illegal rooftop subletted rooms the only factor causing such tragedies?

Comment: Thank you JR. I love how you dissect the sentence. When I wrote the sentence, I was pretty sure it should be “causes”, since the clause modified the factor. It’s my friend who got confused by my poorly written sentence. I didn’t know mixing a plural noun with a singular one would cause such confusion... Why shouldn’t I mix them? That “rooms” is “a factor”, and the clause modifies “a factor”, isn’t it?

Answer (score 2):

You ask if there is anything else unnatural in the sentence.

> ...eliminating highly susceptible places or circumstances for fire...

I would change the order to say this.

> ...eliminating places or circumstances highly susceptible to fire...

First *susceptible for* is odd. And when you separate that from the thing in question (fire) we start wondering what a "susceptible place" is. For example, a *susceptible mind* is a thing (and M-W's example).

Comment: I agree, but there is more here that is problematic. Circumstances don't burn.

Comment: My friend told me that the sentence was odd, so he suggested me to change the “to” to “for”, which I don’t understand. I like your version. It makes my sentence sounds a lot better. Thank you very much Cxed.